# How to combine 2 Grails app, sharing the same database?

Tags: mysql, grails

Currently I have a Grails app X which uses database X, and

I have another Grails app Y which uses database Y.

Besides pointing the Grails app Y to database X, what should I do/change so that it won't affect the existing data in the database X when I run app Y.

There are some domain classes which are same for grails app X and Y, only attributes are different.

Will it affect the existing data in database X when I run app Y ?

Below is the datasource.groovy for Grails app Y (I have pointed to database X, what else I should change?):

```
environments {
     development {
          dataSource {

            dbCreate = "update" 
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testingX?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"     //I have point to database X

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, that's all you need to do. I'm sure you had a look at this:
[Grails Datasource](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#dataSource)

Comment: This is an interesting setup. What if both applications are working with a (partly) shared set of data. Because of the hibernate cache, it would be a delay (in one application) in seeing new inserted data by the other application?